# What does this mean 先月　何日　会社を　やすみましたか。

Tags: meaning

I come across the following sentence:

```
先月　何日　会社を　やすみましたか。
```

I am confused about that this is actually asking. Is it asking:

1. How many days of holidays did the company have last month?
2. Which date did the company have holiday last month?

Please help.

Comment: If you want to ask "Which date ~ ?", you have to say 「何日<b>に</b>」 "_on_ which date".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

会社をやすむ means "to take (a day) off work"; if the company was having a holiday it would be 会社はやすみです. So this clearly means "How many days did you take off work last month?"

I am a BrE native speaker, so the American may well be different, if that's relevant. Oh, and I make mistakes sometimes.